# AWS DynamoDB Stream how to identify records that was created in different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb global table and lambda is listening on the streams, the lambda is configured in both regions, But I want the lambda to process that only in one region (original region)
Is there a way to identify the records in dynamo db streams for records for the region where it is actually created?

Comment: No, unless you add such attribute to your items.

Comment: ya, that's what I thought too. I could not find any from the resources related to this